# Three.js bump map not updating

Tags: javascript, three.js, bump-mapping

I have a `.obj` model with the corresponding `.mtl` file loaded in my scene. I'm applying a `bumpMap` to it after being loaded:

```
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setPath('/models/');
        mtlLoader.load('model.mtl', function (materials) {
            materials.preload();

            // Load obj file
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('/models/');
            objLoader.load('model.obj', function (group) {

                var geometry = group.children[0].geometry;
                geometry.center();

                model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, otherMesh.material.clone());
                model.material.bumpMap = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/bump.png');
                model.name = "obj model";
                scene.add(model);

                render();
                callback();
            });
        });
```

This works as expected. The `map` texture is just a black and white `.png` image. But if I apply the `bumpMap` not just before adding the model it's not applied. For example, with this code the `bumpMap` is not applied to the model:

```
        var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
        mtlLoader.setPath('/models/');
        mtlLoader.load('model.mtl', function (materials) {
            materials.preload();

            // Load obj file
            var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
            objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
            objLoader.setPath('/models/');
            objLoader.load('model.obj', function (group) {

                var geometry = group.children[0].geometry;
                geometry.center();

                model = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, otherMesh.material.clone());
                setTimeout(function(){
                    model.material.bumpMap = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/bump.png');
                }, 0);

                model.name = "obj model";
                scene.add(model);

                render();
                callback();
            });
        });
```

Just adding a timeout and the `bumpMap` is not applied anymore. Adding `model.bumpMap.needsUpdate = true;` after applying the `bumpMap` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have rendered a material at least once, adding a texture *that was not previously present* requires the building of a new shader program. To force that, you need to set

```
mesh.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

See the three.js documentation [How to Update Things](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things).

three.js r.85